# Determine source of QKeyEvent

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5.2

I have a `Qt` application with multiple widgets showing buttons at the same time.  In certain circumstances, I want key presses to be sent to one of the widgets, even if that widget doesn't have focus.  To do this, I have overridden `keyPressEvent()` in the master widget (that owns all subwidgets in this application) and re-send the key event to the subwidget if it doesn't have focus using code similar to this:

```
if (!someWidget->hasFocus())
{
    QApplication::sendEvent(someWidget, keyEvent);
}
```

This works great as long as `someWidget` handes said event.  If it ignores it, then it enters a nasty infinite recursive loop since events flow up to parents.

Is there a way to know where an event came from so I can prevent this infinite loop?  I'm thinking of something like this:

```
if (!someWidget->hasFocus() && (keyEvent->source != someWidget))
{
    QApplication::sendEvent(someWidget, keyEvent);
}
```

Or is there a different way I can prevent this from happening?

Comment: `QApplication::focusWidget`? Imho, source of `QKeyEvent` is user -> platform API.

Answer (score 1):

When you use signals and slots mechanism you can call `sender()` which can give you information, but here you can do next: use `eventFilter` which can give you information about every `QObject` which sends events to `mainWindow`, so you can catch event and sender

```
    bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
    {
    if(event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)//your keyPressEvent but with eventFilter
        if(!someWidget->hasFocus() && obj != someWidget)//your focus and source checkings, obj is object which send some event,
                                                        // but eventFilter catch it and you can do something with this info
        {   
        //do something, post event
        }

return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

Don't forget

```
protected:
     bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);
```

Maybe you need use `QKeyEvent`, so cast `QEvent` if you sure that `event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress`. For example:

```
QKeyEvent *key = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
if(key->key() == Qt::Key_0)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: It looks like in eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event), 'obj' is the watched object, not the object that is sending the event.  Do you know if there's a way to determine the event origin?

Comment: @KyleL what are the circumstances? Do you choose when do this or this is user actions? Maybe you can do this with signals slots and use sender()

Comment: @KyleL and what you want to do? Catch pressing and set text to other textEdits or what?